# Maleh month with Rosh Chodesh on Shabbos

Tags: halacha, shabbat, calendar, rosh-chodesh-new-month

Does our Jewish calendar contain a Maleh month with its first day starting on Shabbos (contain parts of six calendar weeks), and if yes, how often does it occur?

Comment: "how often does it occur?" How precise a number do you need? On average a month can start on one of four days and it's a *roughly* even distribution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it does. Nisan, Av, Tishrei, Marcheshvan, Shevat or Adar I can be that way. (OC 428:2)